# Develop without referencing the GAC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, gac

Is it possible to develop in Visual Studio *without* referencing assemblies in the GAC (except the core .Net framework)? I guess I'm asking if it's possible to use purely local assemblies for an application.

Our buildserver/live/test environments have nothing installed except the .Net framework, all referenced assemblies such as MVC/Entity Framework etc. are included as NuGet package archives. Development machines need MVC installed for Visual Studio to work properly. The problem with this is, there's no way to tell if something will cause a problem resolving a particular dependency until it is pushed out to the buildserver as development machines will usually find what it needs in the GAC. I've also had the scenario where an older, incorrect version of an assembly was found in the GAC on my development machine even though the later, correct version was referenced by the project as part of a package (which the buildserver used).

Comment: This is the **exact** reason you have build/test environments, to flush out mistakes like that.

Comment: I would rather my dev environment was referencing the same libraries as build and I can spot any problems before pushing it out to the build server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was 2 steps;

1. Remove (or rename to a something which doesn't exist) the paths under your AssembleyFoldersEx registry key. So on my Win7 64bit machine it was the following

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\ASP.NET MVC4 (and Web Pages)
2. Remove assemblies from the GAC. In my scenario this was system.web.mvc and associated assemblies, basically anything installed under

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4 (and Web pages)

Follow the steps here to do this

http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/working-on-aspnet-mvc-beta-and-preview.html

Basically now any assemblies which cannot be resolved by their location specified in the project file (i.e if a NuGet package has an incorrect name) will cause the build to fail in the same way the build server will. MVC templates still work in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Well You can always add a folder "Libs" along with others, and store all Your Dll's in it. And make sure that references point to that folder and dll, instead of GAC.

That would basically mean removing all references from the project, and adding them back again manually to the specific location.

What You can do then, is track these dll in Source control. This way all of them would get pushed to the Build server.

Comment: This kinda prohibits the use of the NuGet package manager, which I'd like to avoid.

I'm pretty sure assemblies referenced in web.config etc. would still reference the GAC as afaik they don't use the project reference so there is no </hintpath>

Comment: Why do You say it prohibits Nuget ? What NUget does by default, is download the DLL's to <SolutionFolder>/Packages/<PackageName>*. You can Include this folder in the SCM if You want.

Comment: This isn't any different to what I have now as far as I can see, just with an extra step of moving to a lib folder after each package install. This still wouldn't stop development machines resolving from the GAC if there was an issue locating the local assembly. I suppose my real issue here is that you can't develop with MVC without installing it into the GAC, which means development machines will never be the same as build/test etc. Not to mention the assemblies you installed as part of MVC, the ones that went in the GAC won't match the assemblies in the NuGet package added to your project!

Comment: So If You want all machines to use MVC lib from packages, install it via Nuget, and specify the reference path in the project to use the one from packages folder. If it's not found there, VS will automatically try to find it in the GAC. I don't think You can change that. What You can do, is make sure VS finds it in the Packages folder, and make sure project references point to it

Comment: That's the problem with the NuGet package manager, there's no real connection between the packages you have installed and the references on the project. It's quite easy for these to get out of sync when versions are upgraded etc. etc. i.e someone forgets to commit an upgraded package or the reference still points to an older package. This only comes to light when everything is published.

Comment: Well If somebody forget to commit a new class that they've developed, project won't build either. If You don't wanna commit the DLL's, You can set up build server to pull all the NugetPackages before build. That's how we've set up our system. And it also works fine